# Passing an object in JNI always returns NULL

Tags: java, c++, c, jakarta-ee, java-native-interface

I am using JNI to pass an object from C++ to Java. But am stuck up somewhere in the code where the 
"GetMethodID"  always returning NULL and getting crashed! The below is the header file I used and the cpp code followed.

> My intention is to return an object from the JNI, Where I always get
>   "emu_response_constructor Null" in the below cpp code.

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_em_Grabber */

#ifndef _Included_com_em_Grabber
#define _Included_com_em_Grabber
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_em_Grabber
 * Method:    getProcessedImage
 * Signature: (II[B)Lcom/em/Response;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_em_Grabber_getProcessedImage
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint, jbyteArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

The below is the cpp file I used. Where the object is getting passed to Java.

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_em_Grabber_getProcessedImage
  ( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint jRows, jint jCols,jbyteArray jByteArray ){

         jclass emu_response = env->FindClass("com/em/Response");

         if (emu_response == NULL) {
             cout << "emu_response Null" << endl;
        }

         jmethodID emu_response_constructor = env -> GetMethodID(emu_response, "<init>", "(II[B)Lcom/em/Response;");
         if (NULL == emu_response_constructor ) {

             cout << "emu_response_constructor Null" << endl;

         }
   int number = 90;
   jobject jEmuResponse = env->NewObject ( emu_response,emu_response_constructor, jByteArray, number );

 return jEmuResponse;

}
```

The below is my java class:

```
public class Response {


    private int age;
    private byte[] result = null;


    public Response()
    {

    }
    public Response(byte[] result,int age) {
    this.age = age;
    this.result = result;
    }

    public int getAge() {
    return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
    }
    public byte[] getResult() {
    return result;
    }
    public void setResult(byte[] result) {
    this.result = result;
    }
```

Comment: could you add your `Java` class?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry I have updated my post with Java class.

Comment: Please also show the `native` method, `Grabber.getProcessedImage()`. It could be a declaration problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to make up JNI signatures yourself. Use the output of javap -s.

In this case it is obvious that you have the argument types out of order.
I think the correct signature is "([BI)Lcom/em/Response;", but don't take my word for it: use javap -s. Always.

And fix your code so that if you do get an unexpected result from any API you don't just print it and continue as though the value was legal. That's what caused the crash.